# c# detect which messagebox (originated in another app) button has been pressed

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

Another application displays a messagebox (with a unique text inside it), user chooses Yes/No. 
How to detect what he pressed in c#? (best in .Net up to 3.5). I could do polling with FindWindowEx (on another thread) but how to detect what button had been pressed? Also I don't think polling is the best way to do the job.

I need to know what the user has chosen in another app, so I can react accordingly in my own app. I don't have access to the other app's source code. Also to make it clear I don't want to click any of the buttons myself. I'm not afraid of a bit of c++, winapi and pinvoke

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's going to be very easy. And certainly not from C#. It's going to need some hooking. What is the underlying problem behind this unusual requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor UI events in another application you can use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). To solve your specific problem you need to subscribe to a particular event (see [Subscribing to UI Automation Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671220.aspx)). To do so call [`IUIAutomation::AddAutomationEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671508.aspx) with a `UIA_Invoke_InvokedEventId` [Event Identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671223.aspx).

While UI Automation can be used to solve your problem, it is an assistive technology, mainly to enable accessibility needs and automated UI testing.

Answer (score -1):

You could use either Anonymous or Named Pipes or WCF(Windows Communications Foundation).

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of the other app.